# Why are inbuilt .sort() functions more efficient than sorting algorithms coded manually?

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I wrote the code regarding this question in python, but my question regards all programming languages.

I generated 10,000,000 random data points and sorted them with quick sort.

On my computer, it took ~57 seconds.

I then generated another 10,000,000 data points and sorted them with the inbuilt `.sort()` function, and it took ~4 seconds.

Why is the discrepancy so large? What sorting algorithm does the `.sort()` function use?

I would assume that the sorting algorithm used by `.sort()` is quick sort, correct?

The quick sort algorithm I used is below (not my code, I used it to quickly test this).

```
import numpy as py
array = np.random.normal(100, 5, 10000000)

def partition(arr,low,high): 
    i = ( low-1 )
    pivot = arr[high]

    for j in range(low , high): 
        if   arr[j] <= pivot: 
            i = i+1 
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i] 

    arr[i+1],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[i+1] 
    return ( i+1 )

def quickSort(arr,low,high): 
    if low < high: 
        pi = partition(arr,low,high) 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1) 
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high) 
quickSort(array, 0, len(array)-1)
print("done")
```

Comment: Python is a bad study case for this, because the builtin / module functions are likely written in C and compiled to machine code, while Python code needs to be interpreted, which is often orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Yup, C. In general, comparing C code and Python code is like comparing Porsches to bicycles. Even if you take the same route, a Porsche will likely get there faster.

Comment: So if I compiled the code into a .exe it would be the same speed?

Comment: @Chessnut You cannot really compile Python code to machine code (with exceptions to some degree, like `numby`, `cython` and the like). You would need to write in a compiled language like C. But even then I would expect the library implementations to generally be faster, because people usually spent time optimizing those.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: in the case of Visual Studio, I find manual code to be faster than std::sort() or std:stable_sort(), due to generalizations in the standard library code.

Answer (score 2):

Python by default uses **`TIM SORT`** as a the sorting technique.

You can get much info from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timsort/